# Selenium python how to get this text under button

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Hello guys i'm learning about selenium. And i got below html with a text inside

```
<button data-v-0a74e43e="" class="button-primary button-primary--dark pl-2 pr-4"><div data-v-0a74e43e="" class="avatar rounded-full overflow-hidden mr-2 -mt-02"><img data-v-0a74e43e="" src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/97/107e_full.jpg%22%3E</div><span data-v-0a74e43e="" class="text-sm font-bold -mt-02"> Black_catXIII </span><!----></button>
```

How could i get this text "Black_catXIII" with selenium and python? Thank you guy so much

EDIT1: This is full html , i could find this element by driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeV5r.jpg)/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeV5r.jpg)/div/div[3]/div[2]') and via debugger it had a text but due to it's   *elements* so i dont know how to retrieve[image]

```
<div data-v-0a74e43e="" data-v-2347e6ae="" class="flex"><div data-v-0a74e43e="" class="flex items-center mr-4"><a data-v-0a74e43e="" href="/withdraw" class="link text-sm font-bold"> Withdraw </a></div><div data-v-0a74e43e="" class="flex items-center mr-2"><a data-v-0a74e43e="" href="/deposit" class="button-primary button-primary--gold px-4 xxl:px-6"> Deposit </a></div><div data-v-0a74e43e="" class="flex items-center mr-2"><div data-v-4db070a8="" data-v-0a74e43e="" class="relative"><div data-v-4db070a8="" class="balance"><div data-v-4db070a8="" class="relative mr-2"><div data-v-4db070a8="" id="total-balance" class="w-18 h-18 fill-current"><svg data-v-4db070a8="" viewBox="0 0 22 22" class=""><path data-v-4db070a8="" d="M21.72 4a.86.86 0 000-.17c0-1.7-4.44-3.09-9.93-3.09S1.9 2.14 1.9 3.84a1.46 1.46 0 000 .22.86.86 0 01-.04-.06v2.55c0 .55.61 1.15 1.68 1.7 0 0 2.63 1.58 8.26 1.64a21.28 21.28 0 007-1.09c1.82-.64 2.91-1.46 2.91-2.19V4.05a.28.28 0 000-.09.08.08 0 01.01.04zM4.37 3.31c.73-1 3.78-1.71 7.43-1.71s6.78.75 7.46 1.74a.72.72 0 01.14.41v.41a2.55 2.55 0 00-.4-.32c-1.07-.76-3.9-1.2-7.18-1.2s-6 .4-7.1 1.14a1.73 1.73 0 00-.49.38v-.41a.77.77 0 01.14-.44zm15.52 6.46v2.55c0 .73-1.08 1.55-2.91 2.2a21 21 0 01-7 1.08c-5.67-.06-8.3-1.6-8.3-1.6C.61 13.42 0 12.82 0 12.27v-2.5a.28.28 0 010-.09.76.76 0 010-.16C0 9 .57 8.38 1.55 7.9V8c0 .58.67 1.21 1.85 1.78 0 0 2.58 1.38 8.1 1.55a19.56 19.56 0 007-1.08 10.48 10.48 0 001.32-.56 1 1 0 01-.08.28 1.59 1.59 0 00.12-.27zM22 15.41v2.5c0 .55-.61 1.15-1.68 1.7 0 0-2.63 1.57-8.27 1.63a21 21 0 01-7-1.08C3.19 19.52 2.11 18.7 2.11 18v-2.68a1.89 1.89 0 00.09.21 10.35 10.35 0 001.23.52 19.78 19.78 0 007 1.08c5.52-.18 8.1-1.55 8.1-1.55 1.17-.57 1.85-1.2 1.85-1.78v-.08c1 .48 1.54 1 1.54 1.65v-.06a.28.28 0 01.08.1z"></path></svg></div></div><span data-v-4db070a8="" class="font-bold xl:text-sm"><span data-v-4db070a8="" class="whitespace-no-wrap font-numeric">1.15</span></span><!----></div></div></div><div data-v-0a74e43e="" class="flex items-center mr-2"><button data-v-0a74e43e="" class="button-primary button-primary--dark pl-2 pr-4"><div data-v-0a74e43e="" class="avatar rounded-full overflow-hidden mr-2 -mt-02"><img data-v-0a74e43e="" src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/97/9758645300ccdf9d7c2cf31ac75c9ec2086e107e_full.jpg"></div><span data-v-0a74e43e="" class="text-sm font-bold -mt-02"> Black_catXIII </span><!----></button></div></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure the elements you provided here have unique locators. Can you share a link to that web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[contains(@class,'button-primary')]/span").text
```

Comment: it's working . Thank you so much :D .Could you please explain above command? how could you know it .  Thank you so much :D

Comment: thank you :). Always write a relative xpath. So here, I am looking for a button that contains a class name 'button-primary'. Get the following span bcoz thats where your text exist. and use the text method on the webelement to get the actual text

Comment: i edited my 1st post, and my first approach í tried to get father path. and as you can see via screenshot , it had a text, but i can't located it in result. Do you have any idea? If you have discord or any messenger could you add me :D

Comment: which text you are referring to?

Comment: as the same as before. it's Black_catXIII in the picture. due to it's elements so i don't know how to locate it in result and export it. I tried text function but it throw an error

Comment: I am not seeing Black_catXIII in the picture. Please share the html?

Comment: The last line in picture :D it's the result pycharm debugger show me with my approach. but the problem here is i don't know how to export this text result from list. Due to my command is using "driver.find_elements_by_xpath" not element so the result is a list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232596/discussion-between-itronic1990-and-neosteam).

Answer (score 1):

I expect this is not your full HTML, but from what we can see that text is inside the only `span` element present. This means you could print the text with the following line in python:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span').get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

If this doesn't work you'll need to provide the full HTML to identify a unique selector.

Comment: it's not working :D btw i added full html about this button.

Comment: This is error "'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_element_by_css_selector'" with full command "steam_id = driver.get_element_by_css_selector('span').get_attribute('innerHTML')". BTW i edited my 1st post could you give a look. Thank you so much

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's `find_element...`, not `get_element...`, I messed up the syntax off the top of my head. My updated answer should work.

Comment: no problem. i tried your change code and it's working too :D Thank you so much